# Switch to HTTPS - does backlink value to HTTP drop?

Tags: seo, https, backlinks

When switching from HTTP to HTTPS, how much of the backlink value is lost in the process?

Has it been documented anywhere what this instant switch does to how Google views & evaluates the backlink profile?

With nearly 100% external sites pointing to the HTTP version of the site, how urgently do we need to gain links pointing to the HTTPS, in order to reverse any damage (if at all) done by the switch?

Comment: If you do a blanket 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, there is no real significant loss as long as the redirect exists. Search on the other hand, will take a while to rebuild.

Comment: Yes, the page-for-page 301 redirects are in place. Just wondering if there have been cases where backlinks get a somewhat drop in value if they are pointing to the http version of the site. Thank you @closetnoc.

Comment: While there is no hard evidence for loss doing a 301, I have to think there is a cost to the 301 redirect, but how much and in what form is debatable. I imagine it is small if at all.